# When I am using google analytics to track a rails app deployed to heroku, which url do I use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, google-analytics, cname

There is the initial heroku app name like something.herokuapp.com, then there is the ssl certified heroku app name like somethingelse.herokussl.com, and finally there is the actual website name www.anothername.com that is cname'd to the heroku ssl address. Which url should I ask google analytics to generate the tracking analytics code for?

Comment: I don't think it matters. As long as you have the Analytics script on your page, it will track the visitors. I changed the domain of my site and Analytics is still working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it with all three urls (the herokuapp, the herokussl, and the domain name I am pointing from) and they all tracked the same. So I guess it doesn't matter which one you pick

Answer (score 0):

www.anothername.com

and you should add setDomainName method before trackPageview, on all pages.

`_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'anothername.com']);`